# Consuming RESTful service with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I've set up a REST service, using Spring framework. The service, simply reads some info from database, and represents it in JSON format. The service works properly when accessing it directly via browser (i.e: `http://localhost:8080/infractions/get?no=2` works just fine.) But, when I try to access it using angularJS, it doesn't show anything! I've followed [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) tutorial provided by Spring official website, and here's how my code looks like:

index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="get.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="getFractionByID">
            <p>Fraction Type is: {{get.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

get.js file:

```
function getFractionByID($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/infractions/get?no=2').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.get = data;
        });
}
```

I'm really new to non-academic programming and I'm rather inexperience, so please help me find out where should I start finding the problem?

**Update**: Error message:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/infractions/get?no=2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Please add the error message that you get

Comment: Is page being opened on `http://localhost:8080/` ? Is a cross domain request otherwise. Note that the tutorial code is old and is not using current angular controller function declaration. Should work though with old version of angular being used. Just not a good tutorial to learn from

Comment: @TomArad Where should I look for errors? I write the codes inside sublime text, and run them inside browser! where exactly are these error messages?

Comment: Look in browser dev tools...F12. See if errors in the console tab and look in network tab to inspect actual requests

Comment: @charlietfl yes it opens. and I'm just trying to get myself a demo.

Comment: How are you loading the index.html file in the browser. You need to serve the static index.html file from a web server. The tutorial link you provided on Spring official website has a section 'Run the Client' go through that section carefully.

Comment: @RArun The Spring Service is running just fine! I can access it via browser.

Comment: @user2946209 "Spring service is running just fine ". Is that spring service serves the index.html too? or is it only serving REST data?

Comment: @TomArad Added the message to the post!

Comment: Based on error it doesn't appear you are opening this page on localhost:8080. Goes right back to my first comment above. That is a cross domain request error. What is full url on the page itself?

Comment: @RArun How should it serve the html file? No They're in different directories if that's what you're asking!

Comment: @user2946209 Is your REST api allows CORS? You need to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' setting in your REST api.  say something like response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  Refer this https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Holy ...! Damn. I had forgotten to add the filter to the service! Thank you sir, it solved the problem. Please post an answer so It might come to use of someone.

Comment: @RArun that's not needed when page is on same domain

Comment: @charlietfl Customer's asked that It should be.

Comment: @user2946209 "that's not needed when page is on same domain" Exactly that's why I wanted to know how are you loading index.html? If the html is served by same REST api server then CORS setting is not needed.